# Sending shopping cart items to email PHP

Tags: php, jquery, e-commerce, cart

I use shopping cart jQuery plugin-  [Cesta-Feira](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Shopping-Cart-Manipulation-Plugin-jQuery-Cesta-Feira.html) to make a shopping cart on my website where you can pick up items and send it to your shopping cart. After you should fill up form with name, email, company name, phone number and text message, there is no payment or anything. The checkout - it's only send your items with from to email. The company will receive an email with orders and contact customers.

So how I should send it? You can see the code of this plugin in the link.

Answer (score 0):

From the website description:

> Cesta-Feira is a lightweight yet useful jQuery eCommerce plugin to add
>   an interactive Shopping Cart to your web app that allows to
>   dynamically add, remove, clear, update cart items on the client side.
>   Based on HTML5 web storage API

This means that the plugin only helps you create interactivity on your shopping cart, it doesn't handle the backend side. You should take care of sending the data to the server, where the backend code will process the data (e.g. to be stored on a database, sent by email, process payments, etc).

If you are not familiar with backend data processing, I suggest you to use a complete e-commerce framework instead.